# ipad media query bootstrap dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using the following media query in my bootstrap app.

```
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and  (orientation: landscape) {
 .nav li { width: 100%;
         }
 .nav .dropdown ul {display:none; }
 .nav .open ul { display: block; }

 .nav-collapse .nav > li > a, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
  text-align: center;
   background-color:#211256;
  }

 .nav-collapse .nav > li > a:hover,
 .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #211256;
 color:white;

 }

    .navbar .nav > li  a:hover{
     color:white;
     }

   .navbar .nav .active > a, .navbar .nav .active > a:hover {
    background: #211256;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
   }

   .nav-collapse .nav > li > a, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
   border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
   color: white;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding: 6px 15px;
   margin-bottom:2px;

   }

   .navbar .nav li.dropdown .dropdown-toggle .caret, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open .caret {
  border-bottom-color: white;
  border-top-color: white;
  }


  .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.active >   .dropdown-toggle, .navbar .nav li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle {
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #211256;
 }
.accordion-inner {
border-top: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
padding: 9px 15px;
}


 }
```

When viewing the page in landscape mode

```
      http://46.32.253.11/
```

the dropdown navbar is open by default and I cant see the bootstrap button, I use exactly the same media query for max-width 979px and the button appears and is closed.

Can anyone advise what selector i need to target to have the ipad show the bootstrap button and hide the dropdown menu until the button is pressed.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

That would require some JavaScript and I'm going to recommend jQuery for sake of simplicity.

Essentially, you're going to listen for the `orientationchange` event in JavaScript and then, based on the orientation, invoke a function that will handle the toggle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.onorientationchange = function() {
    var orientation = window.orientation;
    switch(orientation) {
      case 0: // portrait
        break; 

      case 90: // landscape left
        toggler();
        break;

      case -90: // landscape right
        toggler();
        break;
    }
  }
  function toggler() {
    var toggled = false;
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
      if (toggled === false) {
        $('.nav .open ul').hide();
        $('.nav .dropdown ul').show();
        toggled = true;
      } else {
        $('.nav .dropdown ul').hide();
        $('.nav .open ul').show();
        toggled = false;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Try this out and see if it gets you started in the right direction (pun intended).

Comment: thanks again for your answer Nick, is there a way with CSS to do this? or would i put the jquery into its own media query? sorry quite new to media queries

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot put JS into CSS media queries. What you can do, is listen for the `resize` event and check for `document.body.offsetWidth` on page load. I'll modify my answer to include this.

Comment: The more I think about it, if you're just targeting the iPad orientation, then the `resize` event is not necessary.

Comment: You would listen for `window.onorientationchange` ... Let me revise my answer again.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I will try this out later today and ;et you know how I get on, really appreciate your help

Comment: Nice pun Nick, sorry to say but this hasnt worked, any suggestions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14197/discussion-between-nick-beranek-and-richlewis)